# jQuery click event works only once (Beginner)

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm a beginner programmer in jQuery and I do not understand why this feature can not perform the second time. The first time the button content changes, after two seconds it returns to the previous state and the second time I can not do the same thing. Please help! Regards

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#registerButtonM').on('click', function() {
    $(this).attr("disabled", true);

    var btn = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="register" id="registerButtonM"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Register</button>';

    if ($('#passRegisterM').val().length >= 8) {
      $('#footerButtonsM').html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch"></i>');
    } else {
      $('#footerButtonsM').html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch"></i>');
      setTimeout(function() {
        $('#footerButtonsM').html('');
        $('#footerButtonsM').html(btn);
      }, 2000);
    }
  });
});
```

EDIT:
html:

```
<div class="modal fade hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="registerM" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xs" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Register on TaskSave</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
      <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="register-input">
              <p>User <span class="" id="vUserM"></span></p>
              <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="user" id="userRegisterM" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="register-input">
              <p>E-mail <span class="" id="vEmailM"></span></p>
              <input type="text" placeholder="mail@example.com" name="email" id="emailRegisterM" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12">
            <div class="register-input">
              <p>Password <span class="" id="vPassM"></span></p>
              <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pass" id="passRegisterM" />
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
          <div class="col-xs-12 register-captcha">
            <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="footerButtonsM">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="register" id="registerButtonM"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Register</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-- /.modal -->
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your `#footerButtonsM` HTML to

```
  <div class="modal-footer" id="footerButtonsM">
    <i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch" style='display:none'></i>
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="register" id="registerButtonM"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Register</button>
  </div>
```

and your jquery code to:

```
$(document).ready(function() {

  var btnWrapper = $('#footerButtonsM');
  var loading = $('#footerButtonsM .fa-circle-o-notch');

  $('#registerButtonM').on('click', function() {

    var btn = $(this);

    btn.hide();
    loading.show();

    if ($('#passRegisterM').val().length <= 8) {
        setTimeout(function(){
          loading.hide();
          btn.show();
        }, 2000)
    }
  });
});
```

The result will be the same, but the approach is better.

Comment: Sincerely? I do not know why I did not get it. This time for me is not good for programming: P. The simplest solution. Thank you very much for help! :) P.S: Sorry for my English.

Answer (score 0):

The reason this doesn't work is that you're removing the button on click of the button.  This causes it to not be bound any more.

When you do:  `$('#footerButtonsM').html('');` this removes the button from the dom object and you lose the early binding that you've setup.

Then you put another button back on the page when you do `$('#footerButtonsM').html(btn);`

Since this is a completely new button it is no longer bound by the click handler that you have setup.

You have a couple options to fix this issue.  You can either rebind or a new click handler either early or late binding to the new button.

A quick fix is to change it to late bind by changing :

```
$('#registerButtonM').on('click', function() {
```

to be:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#registerButtonM', function() {
```

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/b868bbL2/7/) of this working

Comment: can you post your html?

Comment: I added my HTML modal.

Comment: `$(this)` in `setTimeout` == `Window`

Comment: Dan, so what should I do?

Comment: Avitus, will you give an example?

Answer (score 0):

To setup late binding, change

```
 $('#registerButtonM').on('click', function() {
```

To this:

```
 $(document).on('click', '#registerButtonM', function() {
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you have remove the html button from the DOM the onclick handler is autmotically garbaged (this makes sense since the  element present does not exist).

An alternative  is to declare and function named `clicker`.. When you remove and insert the html simply add the function clicker to the new button

See snippet below

```js
function clicker() {
  $(this).attr("disabled", true);

  var btn = '<button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="register" id="registerButtonM"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Register</button>';

  if ($('#passRegisterM').val().length >= 8) {
    $('#footerButtonsM').html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch"></i>');
  } else {
    $('#footerButtonsM').html('<i class="fa fa-spin fa-circle-o-notch"></i>');
    setTimeout(function() {
      $('#footerButtonsM').html('');
      $('#footerButtonsM').html(btn);
      $("#registerButtonM").on('click', clicker)
    }, 2000);
  }
}
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#registerButtonM').on('click', clicker);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="modal fade hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" id="registerM" tabindex="-1" role="dialog">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-xs" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title">Register on TaskSave</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <form method="post" action="">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="register-input">
                <p>User <span class="" id="vUserM"></span></p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="John" name="user" id="userRegisterM" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="register-input">
                <p>E-mail <span class="" id="vEmailM"></span></p>
                <input type="text" placeholder="mail@example.com" name="email" id="emailRegisterM" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12">
              <div class="register-input">
                <p>Password <span class="" id="vPassM"></span></p>
                <input type="password" placeholder="password" name="pass" id="passRegisterM" />
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-xs-12 register-captcha">
              <div class="g-recaptcha" data-sitekey=""></div>
            </div>
          </div>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer" id="footerButtonsM">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-success" name="register" id="registerButtonM"><i class="fa fa-user-circle"></i> Register</button>
      </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```